# Flex Relate field value is blank in List of Sub Panel

Tags: sugarcrm

There are two modules: **Customer** & **Top Transaction**

Relationship between them: **1**(Customer):**Many**(Top Transaction)

There is one 'Flex Relate' field in **Top Transaction** module.

Now I want to display that 'Flex Relate' value on sub panel list of **Top Transaction** module.

For that I did changes from studio->Customer->Sub-Panel->Top Transaction.

On Customer detail page under **Top Transaction** sub panel it's showing only header of 'Flex Relate' field & **no value**(values are blank).

Does anyone know solution to this?

I'm using 6.5 community edition.

Comment: This sounds like a Sugar Bug. Also maybe no stock subpanel in Sugar contains such a field, causing the field type's subpanel rendering code to get forgotten, neglected or postponed in that version.
I'll see if I can find out if that is a known/documented problem.

Comment: I found bugs reported for this concerning Sugar versions 6.4.5 (defect #56607) and 6.5.9 (defect #61019).

The bug report for 6.4.5 is marked as duplicate (but also as "Fixed in Release: 6.5.8").

The bug report for 6.5.9 is marked as "Fixed/Implemented", but apparently has never made it into a release, if the bug report status is to be believed:

It has been stuck in "Pending Code-Review" and "Fixed in Release: TBD" since February 2014.

My guess is that the CE fix for >= 6.5.9 died together with the official Sugar CE development (except security fixes), which also halted that month

Answer (score 0):

Please check this link for flex relate [Flex relate](http://support.sugarcrm.com/Knowledge_Base/Studio_and_Module_Builder/Creating_a_Flex_Relate_Field/)

Try to use relate field instead of  flex related i think it will solve your problem .

Comment: Then how would I be able to link with multiple modules?

Comment: you are using relationship for that

Comment: creating relationship will create multiple tables & want to display value on ListView under single header, which is also not possible

Answer (score 0):

I know, this is the old question, but here is the solution I have found.
Add these 2 fields in the subpanel metadata and this would show the parent/flex field properly.

However there is still an issue in that, here the target module is fixed. I will update this as soon as I find any solution to it.
Untill that, I think this is achievable in process_record hook. But, I am looking for some generic solution.

```
    'parent_type' =>
    array(
        'usage' => 'query_only',
    ),
    'parent_name' =>
    array(
        'width' => '10%',
        'vname' => 'LBL_FLEX_RELATE',
        'id' => 'parent_id',
        'link' => true,
        'widget_class' => 'SubPanelDetailViewLink',
        'target_module' => 'AOS_Invoices',
        'target_record_key' => 'parent_id',
        'default' => false,
    ),
```